# I broke my steering coil, where could I get I new one?

Tags: remote-control, components

I broke this coil:

[image]

Does anyone know where I can pick up a similar coil? It was placed in my Nikko RC toy car (Nikko Tiger 2).

Comment: I am getting tired of fixing your images for you.  Your original was 1757 x 1989 pixels, which is way more than needed, especially when considering it was fuzzy anyway due to bad focus.  This one is cropped to show the relevant part and shrunk to 300 maximum dimension, and contains the same information as your original.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, this is not a negative for someone, they are giving us all the detail we may need, not knowing what is important, for everyone else it re-sizes, if this is an issue for you make a feature request or make a site policy request on meta.

Comment: @Kortuk: I didn't downvote this question nor did I vote to close it. I only left the comment above after fixing the image. The comment was because I did basically the same thing for the same user just a day or two ago.

Comment: I realize you're frustration, but making comments like this is not okay, this is not site policy, and, as I have said before, for ask the user issues we can have, already this user tries to give us what we need to answer instead if just excluding images. This picture has also lost detail now, part on meta if you want a policy on this

Comment: @Kortuk - I agree with the point Olin makes, and we all know how he reacts to things like this. In [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36283/why-dont-my-coil-work) Jason posted two 8 megapixel images, where 200 k would have done nicely. He just dumps the images straight from his camera to the site, too lazy to resize them. Or should we consider ourselves lucky that he doesn't own a 50 megapixel Hasselblad H4D-50?

Comment: @stevenvh Again, of all the issues we have, this just seems like a minor one to me, but take it to meta and ask about making a policy.Or a feature request to allow resize done through the site easily.

Comment: @Kortuk: No detail was lost in my resizing because of the focus.  The original larger image only had more blurry pixels.  I did the equivalent of taking a 10 kHz signal sampled at 10 MHz and resampled it to 100 kHz.  Note my shrunk picture is still a bit blurry.  A larger version would contain nor more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are that this was custom made for Nikko, and that it isn't for sale is shops. If you want the same thing you'll have to buy a new car.

But look at the functionality. It looks like the white dingus rotates and the pin pushes against something. You can do the same thing with a RC servo, though you'll have to change the way you control it. RC servos are pulse width controlled, typically 1 ms to 2 ms repeated at 20 Hz to 50 Hz.

Comment: Yeah, i'm thinking of a stepper motor to replace the whole thing :)

Comment: @Jason94 - why a stepper motor? They're not easier to control than servos, and they consume more power. The servo also responds Damn Fast™.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing magic about a coil.  It is wire wrapped around a core.  You don't say how exactly this coil was "broken", but I'm figuring one of the lead wires broke off.  The windings look quite accessible, so you should be able to find where the wire broke off and unwind it a little to get enough of a lead to solder a better wire to.  I'd then hot glue the joint down as a strain relief so that the thin magnet wire doesn't get flexed.  A half a turn less isn't going to matter to the operation of this coil.